# Set volley JSON Object params in another class

Tags: android, android-volley

I have wallpaper app. App sent [json](/questions/tagged/json) request using volley.

```
 public void getJsonResponsePost() {

    pDialog.setMessage("Downloading json...");
    pDialog.show();
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap();
    params.put("table", "animal");
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(params);
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, script, json,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    // Do Something with response.

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    jsonObjectRequest.setTag(REQ_TAG);
    jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            0,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    MySingleton.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);

}
```

Server get table input and then send [json](/questions/tagged/json) response from database.
Now i want that user can filter images. I have a custom dialog where user can choose their choice with radio button. When user select an image and submit, i want that params of volley request should change like this .

```
params.put("table", "animal");
// to
params.put("table", "nature");
```

Custom dialog code

```
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int radioButtonID = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) 
            radioGroup.findViewById(radioButtonID);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),radioButton.getText(), 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       // Set param for volley here from radio button value.
        }
    });
```

Comment: so do it, whats the problem?

Comment: how can i do it ? Many problem like - getting all variable and how to change data in recycler ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use -

```
int id = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
String text = "";
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap();
if(id == your_first_radio_button_id) {
    // First radio button is selected.
    text = firstRB.getText().toString();
} 
if(id == your_second_radio_button_id) {
    // Second radio button is selected.
    text = secondRB.getText().toString();
}
if(!text.equals("")) {
     params.put("table", "nature");
}
else {
    params.put("table", "animal");
}
```

Comment: how to send params to volley request ? If i start a new request than have to define many variable .

Comment: You could refer documentation, how to use volley.

Comment: Cant find the documentation.

Comment: Tell me how to send this param from CustomDialog class to MainActivity, so i don't have write onResponse and other code again ?

Comment: You can use intent to pass these to another activity. And volley docs - https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple